# Same package, different versions in same project c#

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, azure-form-recognizer

In .Net Core, I have a project which needs different versions of a library (AZ Form Recognizer) because it has different features available on different versions.

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.AI.FormRecognizer" Version="4.0.0" Aliases="V4.0.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="Azure.AI.FormRecognizer" Version="4.1.0-beta.1" Aliases="VBeta"/>
```

The only package downloaded into the project is the 4.1.0-beta.1 version. Ideally I want both dll's available to me at compile time so that I can use both the versions in my code Is it possible in .Net to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean by recognized? You have code in your project referencing both versions, one by way of its alias I take it? And does the code run?

Comment: The only package downloaded into the project is the 4.1.0-beta.1 version. Ideally I want both dll's available to me at compile time so that I can use both the versions in my code.

Comment: Okay, so perhaps phrase your question more precisely. Obviously if a dependency is not installed it cannot be used and it will not be packaged in the output.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [How to resolve .NET reference and NuGet package version conflicts](https://michaelscodingspot.com/how-to-resolve-net-reference-and-nuget-package-version-conflicts/)

Comment: Thanks @user09938 the link seems to be very helpful.